# Running controller_manager spawner with /mybot/robot_description?

Tags: ros, controller-manager, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Should I be able to have controller_manager spawner running inside the /mybot namespace and have it find /mybot/robot_description?  Right now with Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo I am only getting

```
  Could not find parameter robot_description on parameter server
  Failed to parse urdf file
  Initializing ... failed
  ...
```

If I load the robot_description to /robot_description even while keeping the spawner in the /mybot namespace it will work again, suggesting that something downstream from the spawner is only looking at a hardcoded /robot_description rather than respecting namespaces.

---

Update:

I've done a little digging and it seems perhaps the problem lies in a service call to load_controller loses namespace information, the service provider (which is in /gazebo) just looks up "robot_description".  It seems like if I where to launch gazebo within the /mybot namespace it would find the description (and break other things maybe), but then if that were the only way to do that then that means multiple robots with different robot_descriptions wouldn't be possible?

In my urdf I have a gazebo_ros_control plugin loading with the  set to /mybot/robot_description - should that make the loading of the controller work (though it isn't for me currently)?  I do see messages like `Starting gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: /mybot` and `gazebo_ros_control pulgin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [/mybot/robot_description] on the ROS param server.`

---

Update

I've replicated making everything run inside this with my forked copy of gazebo_ros_demos https://github.com/lucasw/gazebo_ros_demos, I can successfully launch gazebo with

```
roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch
```

And that works in the current state, though I had to put /mybot in more places than I'd like (rather than being able to put it an one level in the launch file and no lower level configuration files having to know about it and just operating on relative namespaces.  (gazebo gets launched via empty_world.launch and that doesn't work within a namespace (more descriptive comments in the launch file)

But I can't get the controller nodes to launch properly from here:

```
roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch
```

If I don't put the spawner inside mybot (and everything else is) I get:

```
[INFO] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:121 : Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller [WARN] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:138 : Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
```

or if I do try to load the spawner within mybot:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher
[INFO] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:121 : Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[INFO] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:126 : Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:134 : Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:189 : Loading controller: joint_state_controller
[ERROR] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:195 : Failed to load joint_state_controller
[INFO] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:189 : Loading controller: joint1_position_controller
[ERROR] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:195 : Failed to load joint1_position_controller
[INFO] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:189 : Loading controller: joint2_position_controller
[ERROR] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:195 : Failed to load joint2_position_controller
[INFO] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:197 : Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: 
[INFO] /opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner:206 : Started controllers:
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198929/running-controller_manager-spawner-with-/mybot/robot_description?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2014-12-04

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crzx5](https://answers.ros.org/users/20244/crzx5/) on 2015-03-09**:
Lucas, did you ever find a solution to this? Thanks.

**Comment by [congleetea](https://answers.ros.org/users/9491/congleetea/) on 2015-05-02**:
I alse meet this problem, can you give me some help about it . thanks very much.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-05-25**:
To understand the situation: In which namespace is the `gazebo_ros_control` plugin being spawned? `/mybot`?. If you load the robot description under `/mybot/robot_description` the plugin fails to load, but if you do it under `/robot_description` it works?.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-06-15**:
I didn't ever solve this directly, I just restructured to avoid it.  I'm going to have to recreate this  int the form of a simple example to demonstrate it.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-06-15**:
I've updated the question to link to github where I've recreated the problem.

**Comment by [bahom](https://answers.ros.org/users/25516/bahom/) on 2016-01-09**:
Hy, have you solved this point because I'm having exactly the same problem on Jade.
I did this tutorial http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control&cat=connect_ros  but the warning is hold "Controller spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface". Thanks a lot

**Comment by [filipposanfilippo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21802/filipposanfilippo/) on 2016-04-20**:
Having the same problem on Jade. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `spawner` should be [taking its namespace into account](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/blob/indigo-devel/controller_manager/scripts/spawner#L115-L117) when looking for its associated `controller_manager`. So if the `spawner` node and the `controller_manager` are in the *same* namespace (e.g., `/` or `/my_robot`), things should work.

If you observe a different behavior, please [open an issue](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/issues), preferably accompanied with a patch.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-06-17**:
When I put them in the same namespace, then I'm back at /gazebo urdf model.cpp 'Could not find parameter robot_description on parameter server'.  If I put another copy of robot_description at the root it is found and it works, but that defeats my purpose of putting it into another namespace.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-06-17**:
I think the spawner is working fine, the problem is on the other end https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/jade-devel/gazebo_ros_control/src/gazebo_ros_control_plugin.cpp#L93 - if I set robotParam to the exact absolute location /mybot/robot_description it still doesn't find it.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-06-17**:
But it is strange because gazebo_ros_control had on startup found the right robot_description and was happy, it was just when the service call arrived to start a controller where it looked for it again (why?  Didn't it already have it?) in the wrong place and failed.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-06-17**:
https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/134

**Comment by [webvenky](https://answers.ros.org/users/22361/webvenky/) on 2015-09-14**:
@lucasw Were you able to find a solution to this?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-08-15**:
I haven't tried it but I think this shows it having been fixed https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/112 - I'm in kinetic and it still wasn't working though using the ubuntu packages (or was my config bag?), I'll try the source later.

**Comment by [Mav16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27867/mav16/) on 2017-02-20**:
@lucasw Did you compile from source yet? I used `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-control ros-indigo-ros-controllers` today and it still says it couldn't find the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had the same problem for a long time and nothing posted here helped. The solution which worked for me: setting timeout while launching the node
`<node name="base_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="joint_publisher velocity_controller --timeout 50 "/>`

---

Originally posted by [must_off](https://answers.ros.org/users/27801/must_off/) with karma: 21 on 2016-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kleinma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22806/kleinma/) on 2017-06-05**:
This solved the problem for me when loading multiple spawners under different namespaces in the same launch file. Thanks!